# Compute Multiple Average Commands Simultaneously

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

This is a follow-up to a similar post...

I have the following dataset that looks like this. I'd like to select only those who have a "1" for the ESITwoToFive variable and then compute the `AVG` total_ED_LOS for each unique date. I'd also like to do the same for the ESIFourFive variable.

```
ID  CheckinDate  ESITwoToFive ESIFourFive   Total_ED_Los   
 1   Feb 7             1            0             23
 2   Feb 7             0            1             23
 3   Feb 7             1            0             28
 4   Feb 8             1            0             43
 5   Feb 8             1            0             83
 6   Feb 8             0            1             29
 7   Feb 8             0            1             32
 8   Feb 9             1            0             93
 9   Feb 9             1            0             77
 10  Feb 9             0            1             33
```

I was kindly given the following code to use to compute for the ESITwoToFive variable, which works.

```
 select t.checkin_date, avg(t.total_ed_los) as [Avg LOS]
 from [Fast Track Quality Research ESI Levels] t
 where t.esitwotofive = 1
 group by t.checkin_date
```

Desired output:

```
  Checkindate             Avg LOS for ESITwoToFive  Avg LOS for ESIFourFive
  Feb 7                   24                               23
  Feb 8                   54                               30
  Feb 9                   86                               56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using IIf() conditional expression:

```
SELECT t.checkin_date, Avg(IIf(ESITwoToFive=1,t.total_ed_los,Null)) AS [AvgLOStwo],
Avg(IIf(ESIFourFive=1,t.total_ed_los,Null)) as [AvgLOSfour]
FROM [Fast Track Quality Research ESI Levels] t
GROUP BY t.checkin_date
```

Answer (score 2):

The conditional is likely to be the cleanest solution, but just to offer an alternative without conditionals:

```sql
select 
    t.checkin_date,
    sum(t.total_ed_los * t.esitwotofive) / sum(t.esitwotofive),
    sum(t.total_ed_los * t.esifourfive)  / sum(t.esifourfive),
from
    [Fast Track Quality Research ESI Levels] t
group by
    t.checkin_date
```

Comment: I like this! As long as no records have Null, which according to the sample is the case.

Comment: Thanks @June7 - indeed, nulls would need to be accounted for if a possibility in the dataset; nevertheless, I think your solution is more readable and applicable to a wider range of applications. Thanks for your positive feedback!